# How To Line Things Up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get two things to line up for HTML. Instead, I get them on top of each other. What I really want is to have them next to each other like websites do (where at the top you can choose between like 6 things and they take you to different parts of the website).

```css
#home {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#home:hover {
  background: #6495ED;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 105px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Alt {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#Alt:hover {
  background: #6495ED;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 105px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="home">Home</div><div id="Alt">test</div>
```

Comment: could you provide a codepen for this?

Comment: I don't use codepen but you can check it out here: https://repl.it/GagR/2

Comment: DIVs are block-level elements, which means their natural tendency is to expand to the full width of their containing element. You can change this behavior by setting "display: inline-block" on each of the DIV elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another stated, you can use [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)`: inline-block` to get horizontal alignment of block elements.

I also added [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)`: center` to maintain a centered position when hovered, since the size changes. You can change `center` to `top` or another value if needed.

I also removed redundant CSS rules, shrinking your CSS down to around half its original size.

```css
#home, #Alt {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}

#home:hover, #Alt:hover {
  background: #6495ED;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 105px;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 22.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="home">Home</div><div id="Alt">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div>`s naturally stack over one-another as they carry a `block` display by default.

In order to line them up, you may consider setting an `inline-block` display for both the `#home` and `#Alt`:

```
#home, #Alt {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You may also add a `vertical-align: middle` for a better appearance on hover (as suggested by another answer).

```css
#home {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#home:hover {
  background: #6495ED;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 105px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Alt {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#Alt:hover {
  background: #6495ED;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 105px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#home, #Alt {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="home">Home</div>
<div id="Alt">test</div>
```

Comment: Yea. :) You have to wait like 10 minutes to do that :P